# Flutter Gradle Errror! 1 week trying find my out of this

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I'm encountering an error while using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 and Java 19.0.2. Here are the details.

I'm trying to build my project, but it fails with the error message stating that it couldn't find the artifact com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2..

Additional Details:

IDE: Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Java Version: java 19.0.2 2023-01-17
I have already checked the Maven repositories and tried various options, but the issue persists.

Error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2..
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2./gradle-7.2..pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2./gradle-7.2..pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

build.gradle:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 24
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    retrofit2Version = '2.9.0'
    okhttp3Version = '4.9.0'
    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.2'
    dagger2Version = '2.16'
    rxjava2Version = '2.1.9'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.2'
    lifecycle = '2.3.1'

    kakaoVersion = '2.10.0'

    tedPermissionVersion = "2.2.3"

    // Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.3.0'
    mockitoVersion = '3.12.4'

    sourceCompatibility = 19
    targetCompatibility = 19
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `build.gradle` you have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.'` without a patch number after the dot.

So to fix your error, just change that line to:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'`